# Elisp code output style in org mode

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I want to print elisp code result as original but currently it will output with "|" separated.
for example:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(setq my-list '(apple orange peach))
#+END_SRC
```

The code block will output as below:

```
#+RESULTS:
| apple | orange | peach |
```

How can I get output as original style like below:

```
 #+RESULTS:
 (apple orange peach)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `:results output` to the header line:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results output
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default result output type by adding the following code to your `init.el`:

```
(add-to-list 'org-babel-default-header-args:emacs-lisp
             '(:results . "output"))
```